# I cannot get req.body or content of body in post request. code's working fine with hardcoded Json

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

here is my code:
[controllers/task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zSNU.png)
postman:[showing validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG4E7.png)

**i even used a body parser but this aint working either**.
[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgUku.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

middleware should be used before the controller and json_parser is a middleware.
in app.js

```
app.use('/api/v1/tasks',json_parser,tasks)
```

and the second option you can use just before routes, It will work for all routes

```
app.use(json_parse.json())
```

Third option is you don't need to install package
just use

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: thanks the first option worked by itself. do  you know why without using a parser its not getting data from the body.